# CreateFile on KMDF Driver returns file not found

Tags: c++, c, windows, driver

I'm using the code below to create a KMDF driver

```
NTSTATUS WatchdogEvtDeviceAdd(IN WDFDRIVER Driver, IN OUT PWDFDEVICE_INIT DeviceInit)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(Driver);
    DbgPrint("Device Watchdog: WatchdogEvtDeviceAdd\n");
    DECLARE_CONST_UNICODE_STRING(NTDeviceName, L"\\Device\\DeviceWatchdog");
    DECLARE_CONST_UNICODE_STRING(DosDeviceName, L"\\DosDevices\\DeviceWatchdog");

    WDF_OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES ObjectAttributes;
    WDF_OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES_INIT(&ObjectAttributes);
    WDF_OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES_SET_CONTEXT_TYPE(&ObjectAttributes, WATCHDOG_DEVICE_CONTEXT);

    WdfFdoInitSetFilter(DeviceInit);

    NTSTATUS Status = WdfDeviceInitAssignName(DeviceInit, &NTDeviceName);
    if (!NT_SUCCESS(Status)) {
        DbgPrint("Device Watchdog: WdfDeviceInitialize failed - 0x%08x\n", Status);
        return Status;
    }

    WDFDEVICE Device = NULL;
    Status = WdfDeviceCreate(&DeviceInit, &ObjectAttributes, &Device);
    if (!NT_SUCCESS(Status)) {
        DbgPrint("Device Watchdog: WdfDeviceCreate failed - 0x%08x\n", Status);
        return Status;
    }

    PWATCHDOG_DEVICE_CONTEXT DeviceContext = GetContextFromWatchdogDevice(Device);
    DeviceContext->TargetToSendRequestsTo = WdfDeviceGetIoTarget(Device);

    Status = WdfDeviceCreateSymbolicLink(Device, &DosDeviceName);
    if (!NT_SUCCESS(Status)) {
        DbgPrint("Device Watchdog: WdfDeviceCreateSymbolicLink failed - 0x%08x\n", Status);
        return Status;
    }

    WDF_IO_QUEUE_CONFIG IoCallbacks;
    WDF_IO_QUEUE_CONFIG_INIT_DEFAULT_QUEUE(&IoCallbacks, WdfIoQueueDispatchParallel);
    IoCallbacks.EvtIoRead = WatchdogEvtIoRead;
    IoCallbacks.EvtIoWrite = WatchdogEvtIoWrite;
    IoCallbacks.EvtIoDeviceControl = WatchdogEvtIoDeviceControl;
    Status = WdfIoQueueCreate(Device, &IoCallbacks, WDF_NO_OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES, WDF_NO_HANDLE);
    if (!NT_SUCCESS(Status)) {
        DbgPrint("Device Watchdog: WdfIoQueueCreate failed - 0x%08x\n", Status);
        return Status;
    }

    WdfControlFinishInitializing(Device);

    return STATUS_SUCCESS;
}
```

This code works and I can see my filter attaching to the proper devices that I'm setup as the upperfilter for. I can also see my driver registered in WinObj under \GLOBAL??\DeviceWatchdog with a symlink to \Device\DeviceWatchdog. However when I try to use `::CreateFile(L"\\\\.\\DeviceWatchdog", GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, nullptr, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, nullptr)` on a user mode application, the handle is invalid and I get an error code 2.

Comment: call *RtlGetLastNtStatus()* after *CreateFile* fail. what error - `STATUS_OBJECT_NAME_NOT_FOUND` or may be `STATUS_NO_SUCH_DEVICE` ? both this errors translated to `ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND` so *GetLastError()* is bad here - it lost information. I guess you really got `STATUS_NO_SUCH_DEVICE` which mean `DO_DEVICE_INITIALIZING` in device flags

Comment: Do you have documentation on how to include RtlGetLastNtStatus in C++ code? My Google searching is not turning out very helpful.  
That being said, wouldn't  WdfControlFinishInitializing(Device); clear the DO_DEVICE_INITIALIZING flag? I get proper EvtIoDeviceControl callbacks which I thought you couldn't get unless initialization was already completed

Comment: I figured it out. I wasn't creating a separate device for control and was just trying to attach to the filter driver it self. After creating a separate control device, everything is working now!

Comment: @TheRedAgent could you please share more details on "After creating a separate control device, everything is working now!"? If possible share the code snippet you are referring to which will help in understanding the solution better.